# Is it worth use the database MongoDb in ecommerce project?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is the NoSQL database can be used to create applications such as ecommerce shopping cart software?

Answer (score 0):

It is always worth to use NoSQL databases in e-commerce projects. When you are creating online store you should care about scalability, flexibility, high performance and to reduce costs of development.

You can check GrandNode - open source e-commerce application with MongoDB, with it you are able to fully exploit the potential of NoSQL. Compared to the relational database GrandNode is cheaper. Database is free, so you can save a lot of money on application engine.

I've found simple comparition between relational databases and non-relational dabases in e-commerce softwares.

http://grandnode.com/nosql-vs-sql-comparison

Comment: Everything you wrote is a fairy tale. Even that comparison is so full of holes. There's literally ZERO evidence in your answer, it's just wishful thinking. But, hey, that just means NoSQL vendors did their marketing right and got their own flock to use their products. Congratulations.